# React native curve shape for bottom navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[Please check the bottom navigation in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX1b9.png)Good day, 
I have a project where in material bottom navigation middle icon is big compared to other menu icons and the middle icon has curvey edges on it.please point me in the right direction on how to style this curvey edges.currently I'm using flat bottom menu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal code example in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have uploaded an design image.Code is not there because im still anylazing this new project.

Answer (score -1):

[image]"tabBarComponent" can rewrite this tab, so it can help you add Big Button in the middle